# jQuery collapsing list?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

At the bottom there's a tabbed section. The seconds tabs "Details" gives the example of exactly what I want to accomplish. You can show/hide each row, and you can show/hide the details within that list row.

Is this part of the jQuery UI? If so, does anyone happen to know what it's called?

Comment: you could always try using the accordion too - http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of jQuery. It is just a simple hide and show on another div.

```
<div class="Control">Toggle</div>
<div class="Content" style="display: none;">Some content you want to toggle.</div>

<script>
    $(".Control").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".Content").toggle();
    });
<script>
```

Your elements can change to anything you want, `LI`, `IMG`, `DIV`.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the ".closest" ... does that look for literally the closest to the request (either up or down the page), or the next closest?

Comment: Good comment, it traverses up the DOM. This is probably not what you want, I am changing, but you should use `next` instead.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple accordion
if you don't want them all to hide. remove this line `$('.contentblock').not(c).hide();`

```
<ul id="accord">
  <li>
    <a href="#">title</a>
    <div class="contentblock">Content</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">title2</a>
    <div class="contentblock">Content2</div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

then ...

```
$(function () {
  $('.contentblock').hide();
  $('#accord').delegate('li > a','click',function () {

    var c = $(this).parent().find('.contentblock').toggle();
    $('.contentblock').not(c).hide();
  })
});
```